# Ansible: копировать список папок, файлы по маске и с исключением

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Стоит простая задача копирования из A в B в Win:

- -- список папок
- -- файлы *.exe; *.dll
- -- исключая файлы с *resources.dll

И как же не просто это оказалось для меня, написать на плейбук. Смог сделать тест модель, но копирование идет не так как надо. + не могу понять как сделать исключение файлов по маске *resources.dll

```
--- #CopyObjReleaseTest2.yml
- name: Rsync some files
  hosts: win24
  vars:
    CopyFrom: D:\Projects\test.v3
    CopyTo: D:\UpdateMachine.v5-Ansible

  tasks:
  - name: find user directories
    set_fact:
      temp_paths: "{{ CopyFrom }}\\{{ 'Obj' }}\\{{ 'Release' }}\\{{ item }}"
    register: resultsss  
    loop:
       - "folder1"
       - "folder2"
       - "folder3"

         
  - name: Find  file 
    win_find: 
      paths: "{{ resultsss.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.temp_paths') | list }}"
      patterns: [ '*.dll', '*.exe' ]
    register: file_to_copy   
         
  - name: Copy the
    win_copy: 
      src: "{{ item.path }}" 
      dest: "{{ CopyTo }}\\{{ 'ObjRelease' }}\\{{ resultsss.results | map(attribute='item') | list }}\\"  
      remote_src: yes
    with_items: 
      - "{{ file_to_copy.files|list }}"
```

Comment: Эммм... может тебе лучше `win_robocopy` заюзать?

Comment: не хочется shell командами пользоваться =(

Comment: С каких пор модуль `win_robocopy` - это шелл команда?